# What are some intuitive ways to have fuel optimal routes?

Tags: openstreetmap, routing

Given a road network and two points: start and end, what are some good <strike>reliable?</strike> ways to ***estimate*** the fuel consumption over a road segment (i.e. a network edge).

My goal is to output the fuel-optimal path ( the one with least fuel consumption among all possible paths) instead of shortest/fastest path. I am working on the OSM raw data only and I have no access to 3rd party APIs/software.

I found it a bit tricky specially when the there is no information over signals and turns. All I have is the vehicle info and the OSM data.

A naive way: the longer the segment the better with carefully chosen penalty so we don't end up with the longest path. Possibly also by incorporating the straightness of the road but don't know how to estimate it given its start and end coordinates. Any suggestions on estimating fuel-consumption for a road segment?

Comment: Maybe you can use values (if available on all ways you look at) for maxspeed=xxx ... highway=traffic_signals ... incline=xxx ... see the OSM wiki for those tags ... or also http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing

Comment: wind and hills will be also important